# Replace / append HREF filetype extension in Javascript

Tags: javascript, replace, foreach, substring

I must be overthinking this. I need to select all anchor tags with the class name `cbs-Line1Link` and if it matches the filetype (ppt, pptx, doc, docx, etc.) then add `?Web=1` to the end of the HREF. So, `ppt` becomes `pptx?Web=1`

```
<a class="cbs-Line1Link" href="index.pptx">pptx title</a>
--------------------------------------------------------
const items = document.querySelectorAll(".cbs-Line1Link");
items.forEach(item => {
  let href = item.getAttribute("href")
  if (href.substring(href.length - 5) == '.pptx') {
    console.log(item)
    return item = item.getAttribute("href").replace(/\bpptx\b/, 'pptx?Web=1')
  }
})
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/timhjellum/3dj6ftyw/)

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just set the `href` in your conditional. You don't need to return anything. Example:

```js
const items = document.querySelectorAll(".cbs-Line1Link");
items.forEach(item => {
  let href = item.getAttribute("href");
  if (href.substring(href.length - 5) == '.pptx') {
    console.log(item);
    item.href = href + '?Web=1';
  }
})
```

```html
<a class="cbs-Line1Link" href="index.pptx">pptx title</a>
```

Better yet, since your extensions can vary in length, you could do something like this to match all of them easier:

```js
const items = document.querySelectorAll(".cbs-Line1Link");
items.forEach(item => {
  const href = item.getAttribute("href");
  const extension = href.substring(href.lastIndexOf(".") + 1);
  if (['ppt', 'pptx', 'doc', 'docx'].includes(extension)) {
    console.log(item);
    item.href = href + '?Web=1';
  }
})
```

```html
<a class="cbs-Line1Link" href="index.pptx">pptx title</a>
```

Comment: I swear I tried that and it didn't work. Of course, this works perfectly! Thank you!

Comment: @TimberHjellum No problem, check out my updated answer for an even better approach :)

Answer (score 1):

You may want to consider using the build-in array filter and map functions.

```js
const items = [...document.querySelectorAll(".cbs-Line1Link")];
items.filter( item => {
  const href = item.getAttribute("href");
  return href.substring(href.length - 5) === '.pptx'
})
.map( item => item.setAttribute("href", item.getAttribute("href") + '?Web=1'));
```

```html
<a class="cbs-Line1Link" href="index.pptx">pptx title</a>
```